# Why mysql Query is running slow even though the explain on the statement says otherwise?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

This is my query

```
SELECT 
    id
FROM
    `MyTable`
WHERE
    `env` = 'default'
        AND (`HTML` = '' OR `HTML` IS NULL)
order by `id` desc 
limit 100;
```

Running explain on it I'll get :

```
Possible keys: idx_env  (related to env field in where clause)
Key: id
Key length: 4
Rows: 200
Filtered: 9.50
Extra: using where
```

From the explain above I understand that mySQL will examine 200 records.
And should not have big performance issues

But what I frequently experience is a slow query of 50", in fact activating slow query log on my Aurora cluster I see the following report:

```
 # Query_time: 49.512712 Lock_time: 0.000065 Rows_sent: 28 Rows_examined: 6795665
```

Seems like there's not a consistent feedback: form the explain examined rows are 200 from the logs are all records...

**EDIT**

env and id fields are already indexed. HTML is not indexed intentionally because it's a LONGTEXT type

also I'd like to add that sometimes running the query on workbench it answers very quickly as expected, but often it takes like 50" to be executed.... and I'm a bit confused about this

Comment: Find a way to run `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` every few seconds and capture/log the result.  It sounds like your index stats are drifting, causing the query plan to occasionally change... you just haven't caught it yet.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot , I see your point. But once I'd verify what your saying what am I supposed to do to avoid the issue?

Comment: It will depend in part on what the alternate query plan looks like.  If `id` is a good choice, you might rewrite the query to use an index hint `... FROM MyTable FORCE KEY(id) FOR ORDER BY WHERE ...` but I believe it's premature to do that, now.  Index hints are best avoided but sometimes necessary to work around optimizer quirks... but without knowing what's distracting the optimizer, I don't want to say "this is the solution." Or perhaps `... FROM MyTable IGNORE KEY(idx_env) WHERE ...` would be a better approach.  That index is not a good bet if there are a lot of rows where env = 'default'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what actual index you used here, but this is probably the index which would improve the performance of your query:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON MyTable (env, HTML, id);
```

This would let MySQL efficiently filter out matches in the `WHERE` clause, using both fields.  And this index also covers the `id`, which you select, and which is also used for sorting.  Note if `id` is a primary key, and you are using the InnoDB engine, you might be able to simplify the index to the following:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON MyTable (env, HTML);
```

Comment: env and id fields are already index. HTML is not indexed intentionally because it's a LONG text type